# cURL POST not submitting the form

Tags: php, curl

I'm doing a project and one of the requests is to automatically submit a form to a random site, which is specified from time to time

This is my cURL code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dati_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Code to get POST parameters :

```
  foreach ($html->find('form[method=post],form[method=POST]') as $forms_post) {
  $n_formPOST++;
  $formPOST_action = $forms_post->action;
   foreach ($forms_post->find('input') as $input) {
     if ($input->type == 'text') {
       $dati_testo[$input->name] = "text";
     } else if ($input->type == 'email' || $input->name == 'email') {
       $dati_random[$input->name] = "emailrandom@gmail.com";
     } else if ($input->type == 'hidden') {
       $dati_random[$input->name] = $input->value;
     } else {
       $dati_random[$input->name] = "random";
     }
   }
   foreach ($forms_post->find('textarea') as $textarea) {
     if ($textarea->disabled != true) {
       $dati_testo[$textarea->name] = "text";
     }
   }
   foreach ($forms_post->find('button') as $bottone) {
     if ($bottone->type == 'submit') {
       $dati_random[$bottone->name] = "random";
     }
   }
```

The problem is that in some sites POST is done correctly and I receive the right answer, which corresponds to the answer I would receive by doing it manually.
On other sites, it seems that the form is not submitted.
I have repeatedly checked the URL that I insert in the cURL and also the data that I pass and if I use them manually it works.
I even tried using online tools that perform POST / GET passing the same URL and the same data that I get in my project and it works.

The url_post is made from url host+form action.
I don't understand if there is something wrong in my curl code, considering I'm pretty sure the data I'm passing to the curl are corrects to complete the POST.

Data :

- Site URL : http://www.comune.ricigliano.sa.it/
- Form Action : index.php?action=index&p=228
- Url_post : http://www.comune.ricigliano.sa.it/index.php?action=index&p=228
- POST data :

  - 'qs' => 'something to research'
  - 'Submit2' => 'Cerca'

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code excerpt per se. The question is too vague to be reproducible by anyone else → Concrete url and fields, and http resonse dumps at the very least.

Comment: I added all the data that i use, If it's required I can add the http response but I need to modify my code cause now I don't get back the http response

Comment: Well, have you actually looked at the POST request in your browser tools? Where else did you get `Submit2` from?

Comment: I posted the code that I use to get "qs" and "submit2".
Yes, I tried to complete manually the form from the browser interface while console was opened and I saw from "network" which are the parameters that are sent when I submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `curl_exec()` function in order to execute the cURL. It takes the `$ch` param, like such:

```
// Execute cURL
curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL
curl_close($ch);
```

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)

Comment: sorry I forgot to say it, however I put both those lines of code

Comment: Okay, how are you checking if the post request was made or not?

Comment: I do this by looking at the page code that is returned to me as an answer and I see that it responds with the same page in which the form is completed, as if it did not go to the landing page in the form's action.

Comment: Please include the URL if it's public, and what the post data is. Let me know when/if you add it so I can try and debug it for you

Comment: I just added in my question all the data. I tryed many time even comparing the result doing it from cURL and from the browser
If u were asking about the URL of my site that is in my localhost so at the moment is private..